# php - use variable variable in while loop

Tags: php, while-loop, variable-variables

I'm a bit confused about variable variables.

What I like to do is print the value of $var1, $var2 and $var3:

```
$var1 = 'a';
$var2 = 'b';
$var3 = 'c';

$i = 1;

while ( $i <=3 ) {
    echo $var.$i;
    $i++;
}
```

I know **$var.$i;** is not correct, but I think it shows what I would like to achieve; the while-loop should change it to $var1, $var2 and $var3;

I've tried the following:

```
$var1 = 'a';
$var2 = 'b';
$var3 = 'c';

$i = 1;

while ( $i <=3 ) {

    $current_var = 'var'.$i;
    $current_var = $$current_var;

    echo $current_var;

    $i++;
}
```

But that doesn't work. I think because $var1, $var2 and $var3 are recreated in the while-loop instead of using the actual value. Not sure if that's correct, but that the only thing I can think of.

Comment: what should be the desired output??

Comment: You could try `$($var.$i)`.

Comment: I ran the above code and output was `abc`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
echo ${"var".$i};
```

Curly braces can resolve to variable names without having to use the dollar-dollar approach.

See: [Variable Variables in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one.

```
<?php
$var1 = 'a';
$var2 = 'b';
$var3 = 'c';

$i = 1;
while ( $i <=3 ) {

    echo ${'var'.$i};

    $i++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this. Then use `array`

```
$my_data = array();
$my_data[1] = 'a';
$my_data[2] = 'b';
$my_data[3] = 'c';

// Method 1
$i = 1;
while ($i <= 3) {
  echo $my_data[$i];
  $i++;
}

// Method 2
foreach ($my_data as $data) {
  echo $data;
}
```

// Output

```
abc

abc
```